# Unable to Call Method in Java

Tags: java, methods

I have created a class. Inside the class, I have created a method called "createVessel()" which should return a string array. I want to call that method from the same class and store the returned string array in another string array variable (not even sure if I can do that).

Anyway, when I call the method, the IDE causes an error and thinks that I am trying to create another method by the same name and suggesting me to change the name. Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong? In other words, why aren't I able to call the createVessel() method? (Note: I will post all the code within the createVessel() method just to add context even though it may not be necessary to answer my question).

```
package submarineGame;
import java.util.*;
public class GameControl {
    //Create Vessel Method

    String[] carry = new String[2];
    carry = createVessel();

    String[] createVessel(){

        // code here that creates an String array of positions

        return positions;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Direct solution:**

```
String[] carry = createVessel();
```

I prepared an example where you can see that this will compile and run (if you have a main method) Simply follow this link: http://goo.gl/fQMpKJ and it will get you to this:
[image: Online Example]

**Why?**
The problem is that you can't *execute* assignments to fields directly in the body of a class - if it's not in the direct declaration of fields. For this purpose you have the constructor where you could write something like:

```
public GameControl(){
    carry = createVessel();
}
```

Then you could stay with `String[] carry = new String[2];` because the `String[]` which will be created inside the `createVessel()` method would override it. Another way would to use a main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    carry = createVessel();
}
```

But of course you then need to also assign `static` to the `String[] carry` and the method `createVessel();`

If you have another question, feel free to comment - I will be back on this question later. Also I can see you are not really familiar with Java so maybe the Oracle Tutorials will help http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

A class's block structure is two-level:

```
class {
    ... declarations of fields and methods

    void someMethod() {
        ... statements
    }
}
```

You put the call where a declaration was expected. The IDE repairal then decided you wanted to make a method declaration.

So put the call in a method, for instance in the program entry point:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ... call here, on an instance
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your call to be like this:

```
String[] carry = createVessel();
```

`Java Class` scope can't have any assignment as you did, only the way above

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call the method from just within the class as you have.

You will have to do it from inside a method (like a constructor) or from the Main function.